# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'Circle' Embedding matplotlib in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to embed an orbital simulation into a tkinter frame, I have the plot working properly I am now just trying to input circles into the graph to represent planets. I have had a look for documentation on how to draw circles in FigureCanvasTkAgg but can't find anything and was hoping someone could help.

Here's the code:

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Orbital Simulation")
fig = plt.Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

gridArea = [0, 200, 0, 200]  # margins of the coordinate grid
ax.axis(gridArea)  # create new coordinate grid
ax.grid(b="on")  # place grid

.    
.
.

def placeObject(self):
    drawObject = ax.Circle(self.position, radius=self.radius, fill=False, color="black")
    ax.gca().add_patch(drawObject)
    ax.show()
```

Error:

> drawObject = ax.Circle(self.position, radius=self.radius, fill=False, color="black")
> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'Circle'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the full error code too please.

Comment: there is the full error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/axes_api.html) instances do not have a `Circle` method. That is part of [`matplotlib.patches`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html), and can be imported separately.

Also, when you add the patch to  the `ax`, you don't need to do `ax.gca()`, since you already have a handle for the current Axes (i.e. no need to [`.gca()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html), which stands for get current axes).

Finally, `Axes` do not have a `show()` method. That is a function from the pyplot module, that can be called as [`plt.show()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html)

If you don't have them already, add the following imports:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
```

And then modify your function to:

```py
def placeObject(self):
    drawObject = Circle(self.position, radius=self.radius, fill=False, color="black")
    ax.add_patch(drawObject)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You are welcome. You shouldn't edit the code in the question: future readers won't be able to see what the problem was, and why the answer helps!